# Child View Controller Nib with TableView

Tags: ios

This is my first time using nib files, and I am using them because I was to toggle two views without bloating the storyboard for easy UI editing. I went with child view controller's so I could separate everything. One of the child controller's will contain table view delegate and data source. So I created a nib with a single view in IB. I dragged in a table view, but it is already doing something odd.

Here is what a table view dragged into a storyboard view controller looks like:

[image: normal storyboard tableview]

And here is what it looks like in the nib file:

[image: nib tableview]

It still has the default California data in it. Why doesn't it say "Table View Prototype"?

I tried to add a cell to it anyway but I couldn't. The first image is what normally happens, the cell is nested. In the nib, though, it won't go into the table view.

[image: normal cell insert] [image: nib cell insert]

I want to make the table view with custom cells, but I don't know what is wrong or if I am missing something since this is my first time using nibs.

Comment: You can use Prototype cells only in UITableViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It still has the default California data in it. Why doesn't it say "Table View Prototype"?

Because prototypes are a feature of storyboards only - not nibs.

> I tried to add a cell to it anyway but I couldn't. The first image is what normally happens, the cell is nested. In the nib, though, it won't go into the table view.

To use a nib-designed cell type with a table view that doesn't come from a storyboard, you must have a *separate* nib for *just the cell* (there must be *nothing else in the nib*). Register the nib with the table view (in code); from then on, when you dequeue a cell, the table view will load the cell from the nib. See this section of my book:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_custom_cells

Comment: Thanks I think that was it. So I need a separate nib for the table view and table cell?

Comment: Got it all figured out now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal that you cannot nest a Table View Cell inside a Table View in a xib file. One possible approach to custom cells with xib files is to create a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and set it as the file owner of your custom cell in the xib file (create a xib file for the cell). Then you will be able to create outlets between UI elements in your custom cell and your custom `UITableViewCell` subclass.

In the following example, I'll use `MyCustomCell` as the name of the xib file containing the cell, and also the name of the custom class derived from `UITableViewCell`.

To register the cell with your table view, put this in your `UITableViewController` subclass:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCustomCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCustomIdentifier"];
    ...
}
```

Finally, in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method you can dequeue a custom cell using its identifier and set its visual properties using the outlets you created before:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCustomIdentifier"];

    // Configure cell using its outlets

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code Daniel. If I didn't have book with this same code, this would have saved me a lot of time.